# c++ boost::function and std::vector don't work properly

Tags: c++, function, boost, vector

I use a vector to store all callbacks, when tasks are finished they will be called.

```
std::vector<boost::function<void (bool)> callbacks;
```

in function A, i store passed parameters(i.e. callbacks) in vector:

```
void funcA(const boost::function<void (bool)>& callback) {
    callbacks.push_back(callback);
    // callbacks[0](true);  // if i uncomment this line, callback works properly
}
```

in function B, where i had finished task, i tried to call them:

```
void funcB() {
    for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.size(); i++) {
        callbacks[i](true); // this line cause error: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_function_call> >: call to empty boost::function
    }
}
```

callbacks, funcA, funcB are members of the same class myClass. I pass parameter to funcA using lambda (from another class):

```
funcA ([](bool success) {
   printf("function works properly\n");
})
```

does anyone know what's the problem? many thanks.

Comment: If you have a C++11 capable compiler (as indicated by your use of lambdas) why not use `std::function` instead of `boost::function`?

Comment: `std::vector<boost::function<void (bool)> callbacks;` Check this line, you're missing something. This will not compile.

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? Is it guaranteed `funcB` gets called after `funcA`? Is multithreading involved?

Comment: typo, should be std::vector<boost::function<void (bool)>> callbacks; @Blacktempel

Comment: i don't know how to use std::function, could you show me?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: It [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9f015cc8825a855), if I fix the syntax errors and assemble your fragments into a test program. Probably, you're doing something to invalidate the functions before calling `funcB`; perhaps you could post a small but complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @swen: `std::function` is almost identical to `boost::function`. It's in the C++11 standard `<function>` header.

Comment: @swen `std::function` works as pretty much a drop-in replacement for `boost::function`; you can say it's a standardisation of the latter.

Comment: thank you all, as @MikeSeymour said, i found the problem is before funcB, i call callbacks.erase() to delete elements; if i don't call callbacks.erase() and call funcB directly, the code work ok